# Vue 2 if countdown timer hits zero hide whole component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

So I'm working on a banner with a timer. But I want to make the whole component hide when the timer hits 0. Here is what I have at the moment:

banner.vue

```js
<template>
  <div
    class="flex flex-col md:flex-row justify-between items-center p-4 lg:px-56 bg-red-700 text-white relative deal-banner"
    v-if="!expired"
  >
    <div class="absolute top-0 right-0 h-full w-4/6 -mr-5 cover"></div>
    <div class="flex jusify-center items-center uppercase">
      <h1 class="text-2xl font-extrabold mr-4 relative">{{ discountValue }}% off</h1>
      <h3 class="text-xs font-medium mt-1">Your first month</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="flex justify-center items-center py-6 lg:py-0">
      <div class="text-center">
        <span class="text-2xl font-medium">{{ days | two_digits }}</span>
        <div class="text-xs font-medium uppercase">days</div>
      </div>
      <span class="text-xl -mt-4 font-medium px-2">:</span>
      <div class="text-center">
        <span class="text-2xl font-medium">{{ hours | two_digits }}</span>
        <div class="text-xs font-medium uppercase">hours</div>
      </div>
      <span class="text-xl -mt-4 font-medium px-2">:</span>
      <div class="text-center">
        <span class="text-2xl font-medium">{{ minutes | two_digits }}</span>
        <div class="text-xs font-medium uppercase">minutes</div>
      </div>
      <span class="text-xl -mt-4 font-medium px-2">:</span>
      <div class="text-center">
        <span class="text-2xl font-medium">{{ seconds | two_digits }}</span>
        <div class="text-xs font-medium uppercase">seconds</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex flex-row items-center">
      <h3 class="text-xs font-medium mr-4 uppercase">Use code:</h3>

      <div
        class="border-2 border-bg-white border-dashed py-2 px-8 uppercase text-base text-center font-bold whiteOpacity"
      >{{ discountCode }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "DealBanner",
  props: ["discountValue", "date", "discountCode"],
  filters: {
    two_digits(value) {
      return value.toString().length <= 1 ? "0" + value : value;
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      now: Math.trunc(new Date().getTime() / 1000),
      modifiedDate: Math.trunc(Date.parse(this.date) / 1000),
      expired: false
    };
  },
  mounted: function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      this.now = Math.trunc(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
      this.expired = this.modifiedDate <= this.now;
    }, 1000);
  },
  computed: {
    seconds() {
      return (this.modifiedDate - this.now) % 60;
    },
    minutes() {
      return Math.trunc((this.modifiedDate - this.now) / 60) % 60;
    },
    hours() {
      return Math.trunc((this.modifiedDate - this.now) / 60 / 60) % 24;
    },
    days() {
      return Math.trunc((this.modifiedDate - this.now) / 60 / 60 / 24);
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
.whiteOpacity {
  background-color: var(--whiteOpacity);
}

.deal-banner .cover {
  background-color: var(--whiteOpacity);
  transform: skewX(-10deg);
}
</style>
```

component render

```
<DealBanner discountValue="20" date="April 15, 2020 12:00" discountCode="Release" />
```

GIF link - https://i.gyazo.com/6da0acde71314b1d9d7ddc65697dba3e.gif

Any help would be great, not sure if I can just use this using expired or whether I need to check if the timer is 0 somehow, maybe computed or another data method or something like that.

Comment: You can use dynamic css or class bindings if you are just trying to hide it in html. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Comment: @securisec I'm trying to hide the whole component only when the timer reaches zero if you could provide an example that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
mounted: function() {
  setInterval(() => {
    this.now = Math.trunc(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
    this.expired = this.modifiedDate <= this.now;
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: OK, I've given this a try but if I set the timer to let's say 23rd Feb the timer goes into minus and the component doesn't hide. I'll update the code as I've re-written the timer ai I'll update the question again.

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to OP's problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.

Comment: I forgot `this` operator in function. Updated my answer